# Imprimir en pantalla 4 columnas, cada una con un caracter diferente en C++

Tags: c++

Me pidieron que elabore un programa con 4 columnas, dependiendo del número de los renglones y columnas disponibles en pantalla de la consola.
Solo se puede imprimir un caracter a la vez (algo así):

[image: Mas o menos así]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: 1.Verifique  cuántos  renglones  (NReng)  y  columnas  (NCols)  tiene  la  ventana  de ejecución de su consola. 2.Divida el número de columnas disponibles en pantalla, de tal manera que la pantalla completa quede llenada con 4 barras de 4 diferentes caracteres. 3.Únicamente puede imprimir 1 caracter a la vez.(cout<<”*”; )     Ya edité la publicación con el resultado que debe imprimir en pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es completar tu matriz con letras diferentes (en este ejemplo que te pongo son aleatorias) debes obtener el valor aleatorio de cada una de los caracteres que vas a imprimir.

Tu código podría ser algo parecido a esto...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char character;
    int filas, columnas;

    cout << "Cuantas filas quieres: ";
    cin >> filas;
    cout << "Cuantas columnas quieres: ";
    cin >> columnas;

    for (int r=0 ; r<filas ; r++)
    {
        for (int c=0 ; c<columnas ; c++)
        {
            character = 'a' + rand()%26;
            cout << character << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Mediante la expresión `character = 'a' + rand()%26;` se obtienen los caracteres aleatorios dentro del alfabeto (sin incluir la `ñ` ya que es considerado un caracter especial).